# Sign a pushed Git commit without amending

Tags: git

Considering the following:

```
git commit -m "I forgot to git commit -s"
git push
```

Is there any way to go back and sign an unsigned git commit that has already been pushed? Is the only way to do this through amending?

Comment: No there isn't. Yes it is. You can create another commit that is signed, mentioning that you vouch for the preceeding commits too but if the signature needs to be applied to the previous commit you must amend.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create a tag on that commit, and signed the annotated tag. See "[Git Tools - Signing Your Work](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work)".

Then you can push the tag itself.